# What is a better way to add different strings to different arraylists in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am trying to parse an RSS feed. I have an RSSHandler for that.

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    boolean item = false;
    int DATA_VALUE = 0;

    private static ArrayList<String> photoUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> hits = new ArrayList<>();

    private static StringBuffer rssResult = new StringBuffer();

    public static StringBuffer getRssResult() {
        return rssResult;
    }

    public void setRssResult(StringBuffer rssResult) {
        this.rssResult = rssResult;
    }


    @Override
    public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName,
                              Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

        DATA_VALUE = 0;
        if (localName.equals("item")) {
            item = true;
            if (rssResult != null && rssResult.length() > 0) {
                feed.add(getRssResult());
                setRssResult(new StringBuffer("\n"));
            }
        }

        if (item) {
            if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_TITLE)) {
                DATA_VALUE = 1;
            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_LINK)) {

            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_DESCRIPTION)) {
              
            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_PUB_DATE)) {

            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_SOURCE)) {

            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_PICTURE)) {
                DATA_VALUE = 2;
            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_HITS)) {
                DATA_VALUE = 3;
            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_NEWS_TITLE)) {
                DATA_VALUE = 1;
            } else if (localName.equals(Constants.RSS_NEWS)) {
                
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
       
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        String cdata = new String(ch, start, length);
        if (DATA == 1) {
           title.add(cdata.trim())
        } else if (DATA == 2) {
           photoUrl.add(cdata.trim())
        } else if (DATA == 3) {
           hits.add(cdata.trim())
        }
       
   }

}
```

How could I avoid using so many if-else in both the functions – startElement() and characters(). I was thinking of using a temporary array list and mapping it to the required Arraylist – (photoUrl, title or hits), something like using pointers in C.

**Could I avoid using so many Arraylists for different kind of strings for my task?**